# Rasa to train datasets

Tags: tensorflow, chatbot, rasa

I just got into Rasa to make a chatbot and wanted to know if there was some way to train Rasa Core on datasets(preferably subreddit datasets) either by its own or using tensorflow or something.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas:
Core training data in Rasa follows a specific story format which to date requires a predefined, closed set of intents and actions to operate. You could use data from a dataset for NLU intent examples and use it to train a model in that way, provided you format it correctly. You could also use data from a dataset to define responses for retrieval actions, if you were wanting to generate natural sounding replies.